# Tracing path of lines in network using QGIS

Tags: qgis, snapping, trace

I am using QGIS 3.

I want to trace the path of lines in network. I found that I can use Snapping Toolbar to trace the lines but in manual and I want to do it in automatic, I give start node and it automatically traces the path.

I have a map and I want to trace the path for each line from start node till the end, then extract each line id. But I want to it in automatic method, not in manual method as snapping tool do.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it with the snapping toolbar?

Comment: I am not aware how can I use snapping toolbar ,I tried a lot but I did not get how can I trace the line and I want to extract all paths possible from the map ,could u do screen shots for me how can I use snapping toolbar and extract id of each line in the path .i need to do that automatic .just give the starting line of and it gives me output.Thanks for helping

Comment: The snapping tool is for manual digitizing, but it sounds like you want an automated solution. Please use the [edit] button to clarify your question.